# SQL insert multiple rows into a second/sub table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, insert

I've been stuck on this all afternoon and finally give up.  I need to create monthly invoices for multiple customers regularly every month.

So I have taken the data from [Customers - Main] table and create all the [INVOICES] rows that I need to.  However, I cannot get [Customers - Invoices] to populate each invoice correctly.  What should happen is that [Invoices - Stock Link] gets populated with the correct information from [Customers - Invoices].  Currently each customers items are all populating 1 invoice.

Here is the code I've reached so far and any help would be gratefully received.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [aa test]

AS 

INSERT INTO dbo.[INVOICES] 
(
    CompanyName, InvoiceDate, PurchaseOrderNo, Terms
    , JobNumber, PrintableNotes, Initials
) 
SELECT dbo.[CUSTOMERS - Main].CompanyName
    , DATEADD(d, - 15, DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m, 0, GETDATE()) + 1, 0)) AS Expr1
    , 'test3' AS pono, 7 AS terms, 0 AS jobno
    , 'We will attempt to collect this invoice by Direct Debit' AS printnotes
    , 'KA' AS initials 
FROM dbo.[CUSTOMERS - Main] 
INNER JOIN dbo.[CUSTOMERS - Invoices] 
ON dbo.[CUSTOMERS - Main].CustID = dbo.[CUSTOMERS - Invoices].CustID 
WHERE (dbo.[CUSTOMERS - Invoices].Annual <> 1) And 
    (dbo.[CUSTOMERS - Invoices].DayofMonth = 15) 
GROUP BY dbo.[CUSTOMERS - Main].CompanyName

SELECT @endInvoice=MAX(InvoiceNo) FROM INVOICES 

INSERT INTO dbo.[INVOICES - Stock Link] (InvoiceNo, StockID, SalePrice) 
SELECT @endinvoice, StockID, Price 
FROM dbo.[CUSTOMERS - Invoices]
```

Comment: What database are we talking about?

Comment: Comment since this isn't relevant - please consider using database schemas instead of putting spaces in the table names.

Comment: Nikola it's an SQL Server 2005.  Norla, I know, it's a legacy database from 1997!  That's why there are spaces in the names.  It's a big job to change all the views and VBA code that goes with it.

Comment: I don't have time to do it now. A pointer - you can use OUTPUT clause in insert statement to send "inserted.InvoiceNo" to a table variable. You can use this information in second insert to isolate new invoices. Unfortunately schema is not very friendly because there is no clear way from invoices to [customer - invoices] needed for extra stock data.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure of your intent, but using MAX(InvoiceNo) is going to return the last invoice generated from invoices regardless of how many invoices your previous statement makes.

Comment: Thanks Nikola, OUTPUT INTO #TmpInv has acheived exactly what I was looking to do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use an [`OUTPUT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx) clause as mentioned by [Nikola Markovinović](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1231866/nikola-markovinovic):

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [aa test]

AS

-- Setup storage for the inserted keys
DECLARE @INVOICES TABLE (InvoiceNo int not null primary key)

INSERT INTO dbo.[INVOICES]
(
    CompanyName, InvoiceDate, PurchaseOrderNo, Terms
    , JobNumber, PrintableNotes, Initials
)
-- Grab the inserted keys
OUTPUT INSERTED.InvoiceNo INTO @INVOICES
SELECT dbo.[CUSTOMERS - Main].CompanyName
    , DATEADD(d, - 15, DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m, 0, GETDATE()) + 1, 0)) AS Expr1
    , 'test3' AS pono, 7 AS terms, 0 AS jobno
    , 'We will attempt to collect this invoice by Direct Debit' AS printnotes
    , 'KA' AS initials
FROM dbo.[CUSTOMERS - Main]
INNER JOIN dbo.[CUSTOMERS - Invoices]
ON dbo.[CUSTOMERS - Main].CustID = dbo.[CUSTOMERS - Invoices].CustID
WHERE (dbo.[CUSTOMERS - Invoices].Annual <> 1) And
    (dbo.[CUSTOMERS - Invoices].DayofMonth = 15)
GROUP BY dbo.[CUSTOMERS - Main].CompanyName

INSERT INTO dbo.[INVOICES - Stock Link] (InvoiceNo, StockID, SalePrice)
 -- Not sure where StockID and Price come from
SELECT a.InvoiceNo, a.StockID, a.Price
FROM dbo.[CUSTOMERS - Invoices] a
    -- Join on the keys from above
    JOIN @INVOICES b ON a.InvoiceNo = b.InvoiceNo
```